# placemarkFromCoordinates geocoding error on flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

No implementation found for method placemarkFromCoordinates on channel
flutter.baseflow.com/geocoding

Here is my Location Provider code:

```
  List<Placemark> placemarks =
      await placemarkFromCoordinates(latitude, longitude);
  selectedAddress = placemarks.first;
```

I have tried changing the method but i dont understand the root of the erro. Is placemarkfromCoordinates depreceated. What is the appropriate way to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same question! Here's a bunch of links and code I've tried researching, nothing works. The above answer doesn't help because it requires the user to type into a text box their location information (placemarkFromAddress, locationFromQuery etc) but in most cases the current location should be automatic!

```
    import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
    import 'package:geocoding/geocoding.dart' hide Location;
    import 'package:geolocator/geolocator.dart';
    import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
    //import 'package:geocode/geocode.dart';
    import 'package:location/location.dart';
    import 'package:flutter/services.dart';
    
    //==============
    //   Attempt
    //==============
    Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
        Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
        //final GeoCode geoCode = GeoCode();
        //final longitude = position.longitude;
        //final latitude = position.latitude;
        // Get the address from the current location
        try {
          //final addresses = await geoCode.reverseGeocoding(longitude, latitude);
          //final first = addresses.first;
    
          List<Placemark> placemarks =
              await placemarkFromCoordinates(position.longitude, position.latitude);
    
          setState(() {
            _currentLocation = '${placemarks[0].subAdministrativeArea.toString()},'
                '${placemarks[0].administrativeArea.toString()},'
                '${placemarks[0].country.toString()}';
            _isLoading = false;
          });
        } catch (e) {
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print(e);
          // ignore: avoid_print
          print('CURRENT LOCATION DIDN’T WORK');
          _isLoading = false;
        }


    //==============
    //   Attempt
    //==============  
     Future<void> _getCurrentLocation() async {
      Position position = await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
      GeoCode geoCode = GeoCode();
    
      // Get the address from the current location
      try {
        // Reverse geocode the latitude and longitude to get the address
        List<Address> addresses = await geoCode.reverseGeocoding(
            latitude: position.latitude, longitude: position.longitude) as List<Address>;
        Address address = addresses.first;
    
        setState(() {
          _currentLocation =
              '${address.street}, ${address.locality}, ${address.countryName}';
          _isLoading = false;
        });
      } catch (e) {
        print(e.toString());
        _isLoading = false;
      }
    }

//==============
//   Attempt
//==============
Future<void> _getAddressFromLatLng() async {
    try {
      List<Placemark> placemarks = await placemarkFromCoordinates(
          _currentLocation2.latitude, _currentLocation2.longitude);

      Placemark place = placemarks[0];

      setState(() {
        _currentAddress = "${place.locality}, ${place.country}";
      });
    } catch (e) {
      print(e);
    }
  }

  //==============
  //   Attempt
  //==============
  Future<Position> _getCurrentLocation2() async {
    bool serviceEnabled;
    LocationPermission permission;
    serviceEnabled = await Geolocator.isLocationServiceEnabled();
    if (!serviceEnabled) {
      return Future.error('Location services are disabled.');
    }
    permission = await Geolocator.checkPermission();
    if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
      permission = await Geolocator.requestPermission();
      if (permission == LocationPermission.denied) {
        return Future.error('Location permissions are denied');
      }
    }
    if (permission == LocationPermission.deniedForever) {
      // Permissions are denied forever, handle appropriately.
      return Future.error(
          'Location permissions are permanently denied, we cannot request permissions.');
    }
    await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(forceAndroidLocationManager: true)
        .then((position) {
      setState(() {
        _currentLocation2 = position;
        _getAddressFromLatLng();
      });
    }).catchError((e) {
      print(e);
    });
    return await Geolocator.getCurrentPosition();
  }
```

- [placemarkFromCoordinates geocoding error on flutter - Stack
  Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75951524/placemarkfromcoordinates-geocoding-error-on-flutter)
- [How to detect user location and show address in flutter web - Stack
  Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64163826/how-to-detect-user-location-and-show-address-in-flutter-web?rq=2)
- [flutter - MissingPluginException for Geocoding package when trying
  to find location from coordinates - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70554673/missingpluginexception-for-geocoding-package-when-trying-to-find-location-from-c)
- [flutter - Trying to find out the current location of the device, it
  is showing "MissingPluginException" - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61803063/trying-to-find-out-the-current-location-of-the-device-it-is-showing-missingplu)
- [[Solved] Flutter: Unhandled exception: MissingPluginException(No
  implementation found for method getAll on channel
  plugins.flutter.io/shared_preferences) (fluttercorner.com)](https://fluttercorner.com/flutter-unhandled-exception-missingpluginexceptionno-implementation-found-for/)
- [Geolocation and geocoding in Flutter - LogRocket Blog](https://blog.logrocket.com/geolocation-geocoding-flutter/#:%7E:text=Just%20call%20reverseGeocoding%28latitude%3A%20lat%2C%20longitude%3A%20lang%29.%20That%E2%80%99s%20it%21,complete%20function%20with%20null%20checks%20looks%20like%20this%3A)
- [dart - how to get geolocation in flutter - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64624629/how-to-get-geolocation-in-flutter)

Answer (score 1):

The geocoding library in Flutter provides several methods other than placemarkFromCoordinates for converting a location's coordinates into a human-readable address or location information:

1. placemarkFromAddress - This method takes a string representing an address and returns a list of Placemark objects that match the address.
2. placemarkFromQuery - This method takes a string representing a query and returns a list of Placemark objects that match the query. The query can be any text that describes a location, such as a landmark, an address, or a city name.
3. locationFromAddress - This method takes a string representing an address and returns a Location object containing the latitude and longitude of the address.
4. locationFromQuery - This method takes a string representing a query and returns a Location object containing the latitude and longitude of the location that matches the query.
5. placesNearby - This method takes a Location object and a radius in meters and returns a list of Place objects that are within the specified radius of the location.
6. placesAutocomplete - This method takes a string representing a query and returns a list of AutocompletePrediction objects that match the query. The predictions can be used to provide autocomplete suggestions for a location search.

Here are code examples to help:

```
// Get placemark from address
final addresses = await placemarkFromAddress('1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA');
final selectedAddress = addresses.first;
print(selectedAddress);

// Get location from query
final location = await locationFromQuery('Central Park, New York, NY');
print(location.latitude);
print(location.longitude);

// Get places nearby
final places = await placesNearby(Location(40.748817, -73.985428), 1000);
places.forEach((place) {
  print(place.name);
});

// Get autocomplete predictions
final predictions = await placesAutocomplete('Times Square');
predictions.forEach((prediction) {
  print(prediction.description);
});
```